# Transforming objects to feature collections in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I'm using GEE to export a panel dataset with population estimates and forest loss in Rwanda 2000-2011. My code is below:

```
//Rwanda admin shapefile
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

var Rwanda = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'RW'));
Map.addLayer(Rwanda);

//Hansen Global Forest Change data
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015')

//Population data
var Allpop = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
  .filterDate('2000', '2012');

var pop = Allpop.filterMetadata('country', 'equals', 'RWA');


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Annual forest loss in Rwanda using the GFC dataset
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var lossImage = gfc2014.select(['loss']);
var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var lossYear = gfc2014.select(['lossyear']);
var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1
    }),
  geometry: Rwanda,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
  });
var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());
print("Annual forest loss", statsDictionary);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Annual population in Rwanda using the WorldPop data
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function newCollectionToImage(collection){
var stack = ee.Image(collection.iterate(function(img, prev) {
return ee.Image(prev).addBands(img);
}, ee.Image(1)));

stack = stack.select(ee.List.sequence(1, stack.bandNames().size().subtract(1)));
return stack;
}


var tch = pop.map(function(img){
var y = ee.String(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).get("year"));
return img.set("year",y).rename(y);
});

var tchImg = newCollectionToImage(tch).clip(Rwanda);
var pop_Rwanda=tchImg;

var Rwanda_annualpop = pop_Rwanda.reduceRegions(Rwanda, ee.Reducer.sum());

print("population", Rwanda_annualpop);
```

The variable statsDictionary (annual forest loss) is an object, and there is very little documentation online about how to transform these objects into something that can be exported.

I would really like to export one dataframe that includes, for each year, the population estimate and the forest loss. Is there a way to transform the object into a feature collection to facilitate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed always a bit of a workaround to rearrange data output from a grouped reducer. To export the result, you'd best transform your data in a feature collection, where every feature has an independent data variable labelled with a similar name. For your case thus the year and the loss area. As a list can be easily transformed to a featurecollection, I used that part of your current code.

```
var statsFormatted = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return ee.Feature(null, { yearString: ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), 
                              lossArea: d.get('sum'),
                              yearNumber: ee.Number(d.get('group')).add(2000)
    });
  }));
print(statsFormatted)
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/89948366256f4bc342ae535b7881d4f1)

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well.

Comment: Perfect. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.